# determine method parameter type from generic typed class

Tags: c#, generics, derived-class

I have the following situation:

```
public class CustomDataGridView<T> : DataGridView 
{
   method1();
   ...
}

class ChannelsDataGridView : CustomDataGridView<Channel>
{
   ...
}

class NetworksDataGridView : CustomDataGridView<Network>
{
   ...
}
```

and I need method:

```
public void Method(TYPE sender)
{
   sender.method1();
}
```

What should be the TYPE in this method or how could I achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you want a generic method:

```
public void Method<T>( CustomDataGridView<T> sender )
```

Note if this is in a generic class that already uses `T` for a generic parameter than you should use a different letter:

```
public void Method<U>( CustomDataGridView<U> sender )
```

Answer (score 2):

A generic method will do the trick:

```
public void Method<T>(CustomDataGridView<T> sender)
```

MSDN has some good formal [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx) on these; but for some more interesting use cases Joel Abrahamsson has a [good blog post](http://joelabrahamsson.com/a-neat-little-type-inference-trick-with-c/).

Comment: It is exactly what I need. Forgot about the generic methods. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1):

You should define `Method` as generic as well:

```
public void Method<T>(CustomDataGridView<T> sender)
{
   sender.method1();
}
```